# Why am I getting AmbiguousForeignKeysError?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've run into an issue after following the SqlAlchemy guide [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths).

Given the following simplified module:

```
class _Base():
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)


class BlgMixin():

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': "belgarath_backup", "extend_existing": True}


class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)

    def create_session(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()


class Player(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "player"

    name_ = Column(String(100))

    match = relationship("MatchResult")


class MatchResult(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "match_result"

    p1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_"))
    p2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_"))

    p1 = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_")
    p2 = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_")
```

That I am attempting to build a query using:

```
dal = DataAccessLayer()
dal.create_session()

player_1 = aliased(Player)
player_2 = aliased(Player)

matches = dal.session.query(MatchResult.p1_id, player_1.name_, MatchResult.p2_id, player_2.name_)
matches = matches.join(player_1)
matches = matches.join(player_2)
```

Why am I getting the following error?

```
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Player.match - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I was pretty sure I'd specified the two foreign key relationships?

---

### Update:

I've tried the following combination as I think has been suggested in the comments but got the same error:

```
p1 = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p1_id])
p2 = relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p2_id])
```

---

### Update 2:

Added some details on what the output should look like:

`player` table:

```
+-----+-------+
| id_ | name_ |
+-----+-------+
|   1 | foo   |
|   2 | bar   |
|   3 | baz   |
|   4 | zoo   |
+-----+-------+
```

`match_result` table:

```
+-----+-------+-------+
| id_ | p1_id | p2_id |
+-----+-------+-------+
|   1 |     1 |     2 |
|   2 |     2 |     1 |
|   3 |     3 |     1 |
|   4 |     1 |     4 |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Query output:

```
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| p1_id | p1_name | p2_id | p2_name |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
|     1 | foo     |     2 | bar     |
|     2 | bar     |     1 | foo     |
|     3 | baz     |     1 | foo     |
|     1 | foo     |     4 | zoo     |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: change `foreign_keys=f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_"` to `foreign_keys=[p1_id ]"` or `foreign_keys=[f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_"]`

Comment: @sahasrara62. Hi. Tried the first suggestion as per my edit above - no luck. Not sure how the second version is different to what I already have?

Comment: i dont think `{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}`  is making any significance, it's is better to define schema in class model iteself, just remove it and try it `foreign_keys="Player.id_")`

Comment: Same error :( Tried lower case `player.id_` but same error again

Comment: don't know if appropriate or not, but change `class Player(Base, BlgMixin):` to `class Player(BlgMixin):` and `class BlgMixin():` to `class BlgMixin(Base):`

Comment: Didn't like that at all :( `InvalidRequestError: Class <class '__main__.BlgMixin'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.`

Comment: What result is this query expected to produce?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - hello again :) I've added the additional details. It's worth mentioning that I've never been able to create a table class with multiple foreign keys that link to the same table. This is just a simple MRE I put together...

Comment: BTW, the FK definition can be made also more simple if you use reference to the key instead of string value. Also no need to specify the column type as it can be derived from the referenced column. As a result, `p1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(f"{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get('schema')}.player.id_"))` becomes `p1_id = Column(ForeignKey(Player.id_))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two-way relationship and multiple join paths prevent SQLAlchemy from automatically determining the joins, and the relationships in both tables emit very similar error messages makes it difficult to understand where the problems lie (and whether a given change makes any progress in solving them).  I found the simplest approach was to comment out the relationship in `Player` until `MatchResult` was working properly.

The changes to `MatchResult` are the same as those specified in the multiple join paths docs referenced in the question.  To get the relationship in `Player` to work I specified the [primary join condition](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) so that SQLAlchemy could determine how to join to `MatchResult`.

```
class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(100))

    matches = orm.relationship('MatchResult',
       primaryjoin="or_(Player.id == MatchResult.p1_id, Player.id == MatchResult.p2_id)")


class MatchResult(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'match_result'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    p1_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('player.id'))
    p2_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('player.id'))

    p1 = orm.relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p1_id])
    p2 = orm.relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p2_id])
```

Once these changes have been made, basic querying can be done without any explicit aliasing or joins.

```
ms = session.query(MatchResult)
for r in ms:
    print(r.p1_id, r.p1.name, r.p2_id, r.p2.name)

p1 = session.query(Player).filter(Player.name == 'bar').one()
for m in p1.matches:
    print(m.p1.name, m.p2.name)
```

---

The above code, for clarity and usefulness to other readers, does not include the inheritance, mixin and session management code that is specific to the OP's application.  Thiis version includes all of these.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import orm


class _Base():
    id_ = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)


class BlgMixin():

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': "belgarath_backup", "extend_existing": True}


class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(conn_string)

    def create_session(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = orm.sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()


class Player(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    name = sa.Column(sa.String(100))

    match = orm.relationship('MatchResult',
                             primaryjoin="or_(Player.id_ == MatchResult.p1_id, Player.id_ == MatchResult.p2_id)")


class MatchResult(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'match_result'

    p1_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(f'{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get("schema")}.player.id_'))
    p2_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(f'{BlgMixin.__table_args__.get("schema")}.player.id_'))

    p1 = orm.relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p1_id])
    p2 = orm.relationship("Player", foreign_keys=[p2_id])


dal = DataAccessLayer()
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=dal.engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=dal.engine)


names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'zoo']
dal.create_session()
ps = [Player(name=n) for n in names]
dal.session.add_all(ps)
dal.session.flush()
p1, p2, p3, p4 = ps
m1 = MatchResult(p1_id=p1.id_, p2_id=p2.id_)
m2 = MatchResult(p1_id=p2.id_, p2_id=p1.id_)
m3 = MatchResult(p1_id=p3.id_, p2_id=p1.id_)
m4 = MatchResult(p1_id=p1.id_, p2_id=p4.id_)
dal.session.add_all([m1, m2, m3, m4])
dal.session.commit()


ms = dal.session.query(MatchResult)
for r in ms:
    print(r.p1_id, r.p1.name, r.p2_id, r.p2.name)
print()

p1 = dal.session.query(Player).filter(Player.name == 'bar').one()
for m in p1.match:
    print(m.p1.name, m.p2.name)
dal.session.close()
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks loads for this. Unfortunately I hit an error when trying to apply this with the `BlgMixin` inheritance. I got `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'match_result' and '%(1826724494728 player)s'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.`

Comment: I've also tried just running with your code without the inheritance. I need to add in the database name: `__table_args__ = {'schema': "belgarath_backup", "extend_existing": True}`. From this I get `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'match_result.p1_id' could not find table 'player' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

Comment: @Jossy I've edited the answer to provide a version that works with the setup in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with the definition of this relationship `match = relationship("MatchResult")` for the `Player` class. If you completely remove this line, and use the below definitions for the **relationships**, all the queries you mentioned should work as expected:

```
class Player(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "player"

    name_ = Column(String(100))


class MatchResult(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "match_result"

    p1_id = Column(ForeignKey(Player.id_))
    p2_id = Column(ForeignKey(Player.id_))

    p1 = relationship(Player, foreign_keys=p1_id)
    p2 = relationship(Player, foreign_keys=p2_id)
```

In fact, the desired select query can also be constructed, but you need to specify the relationships explicitly on JOINs:

```
player_1 = aliased(Player)
player_2 = aliased(Player)
q = (
    dal.session
    .query(
        MatchResult.p1_id,
        player_1.name_,
        MatchResult.p2_id,
        player_2.name_,
    )
    .join(player_1, MatchResult.p1)  # explicitly specify which relationship/FK to join on
    .join(player_2, MatchResult.p2)  # explicitly specify which relationship/FK to join on
)
```

---

I would, however, make few more changes to the model to make it even more user-friednly:

1. add `backref` to the relationship so that it can be navigated back from the `Player`
2. add a `property` to show all the matches of one player for both *sides*

Model definitions:

```
class Player(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "player"

    name_ = Column(String(100))

    @property
    def all_matches(self):
        return self.matches_home + self.matches_away


class MatchResult(Base, BlgMixin):
    __tablename__ = "match_result"

    p1_id = Column(ForeignKey(Player.id_))
    p2_id = Column(ForeignKey(Player.id_))
    
    p1 = relationship(Player, foreign_keys=p1_id, backref="matches_home")
    p2 = relationship(Player, foreign_keys=p2_id, backref="matches_away")
```

This will allow navigating the relationships as per below example:

```
p1 = session.query(Player).get(1)
print(p1)
for match in p1.all_matches:
    print(" ", match)
```

Comment: The backrefs are a nice touch, +1

Comment: @van - hey. Thanks! Sadly I'm getting another error when I remove `match = relationship("MatchResult")`. It happens on `player_1 = aliased(Player)` - `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id_'`

Comment: @Jossy, there must be some kind of typo. your message is not enough information for me to support you further on this.

Comment: @van - no worries. I've accepted an answer now. Marked your answer as useful though for the home/away idea - thanks!