# SQLAlchemy many to one many times in the same table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the classes "Bot" and "Bit", every Bot is going to consist of multiple bits (right now just a left and right arm). I want to do this by having a reference to every Bit a Bot consists of in the table itself, so no association table needed since every bot will have the same number and type of bits.

However, I also want to be able to get all bots that have a certain Bit, and thought I could just back ref the bots to the Bit as a parent but I am then getting this error:

`Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Bit.bots - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

I tried adding the `foreign_keys=[Bot.left_arm, Bot.right_arm]` to the bots relationship but that just changed the error to:

`Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Bit.bots - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.`

Below are my current classes:

```
class Bot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    level = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)

    right_arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('bit.id'))
    right_arm = relationship('Bit', foreign_keys=[right_arm_id])

    left_arm_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('bit.id'))
    left_arm = relationship('Bit', foreign_keys=[left_arm_id])

    image_file = db.Column(db.String(30))



class Bit(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    part = db.Column(db.Integer)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = relationship('Category')
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))
    coordinate = db.Column(db.String(16))
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(30))
    bots = relationship("Bot", foreign_keys=[Bot.left_arm, Bot.right_arm])
```

Any ideas on how to fix it or a better way to do it is much appreciated!

Comment: This is just an idea off the top of my head and may not work at all, but maybe if you have `bots_left_arm` and `bots_right_arm`, perhaps you could do something like `bots = column_property(bots_left_arm+bots_right_arm)`, or just use a `hybrid_property` if using `Bit.bots.any()` in a query isn't needed.

Comment: Also, I think you should be using `back_populates` instead of `foreign_keys` in `Bit.bots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bots = relationship("Bot", foreign_keys=[Bot.left_arm, Bot.right_arm])` will not work for several reasons:

- `Bot.left_arm` and `Bot.right_arm` are not foreign keys, and
- even if they were, the plural in `foreign_keys` is to cover the case of composite foreign keys and not multiple.

What you could do instead is to add the `backrefs` to your relationships from `Bit` to `Bot`:

```
class Bot(db.Model):
    # ...
    right_arm = relationship('Bit', foreign_keys=[right_arm_id], backref="bot_left")
    # ...
    left_arm = relationship('Bit', foreign_keys=[left_arm_id], backref="bot_right")
    # ...

class Bit(db.Model):
    # ...
    def bots(self):
        return [bot_left, bot_right]
```

---

*However, you might consider using Hybrid attributes, and for this i would point you to another [question: Why am I getting AmbiguousForeignKeysError?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880376/99594) which is very similar to yours, and i think that the one of the solutions will work for you too.*